# Change background color of circle in radio button 

Tags: asp.net

I have a RadioButtnList. I want change body background color based on radio button value.

for example change color of background circle to red!

[image]

Comment: I don't change color of background radibutton, i want change color of background circle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user has made selection and depending on the selected value, you would use css to change the appearance of your page.

To learn about how to use the `RadioButtonList` control as well as determine selected values, check out this link: [RadioButtonList example: how to use RadioButtonList control in asp.net](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/radiobuttonlist-example-how-to-use.html) and [RadioButtonList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx).

To learn about changing background colors using CSS, check out this link: [CSS Background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) and [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and [Learn CSS step by step](http://www.csstutorial.net/).

For additional CSS information, check out [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=set%20background%20color%20css#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20use%20css&oq=how%20to%20use%20css&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.3303.7680.0.7870.14.10.0.4.4.0.195.747.9j1.10.0...0.0.U6AFxF62mpQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d6d29e77425191f3&biw=1336&bih=971).

**Hint**

This assumes you want the ***entire*** page to be red:

```
html, body{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really mean to change the 'circle' of the radio button as your recent comment suggests, then you cannot change it.  Radio buttons are native controls.  What you should do instead is to make your own radiobutton-like control using an image for its selected and non-selected states.

Here's a useful link (includes source code) that I think will get you moving: [Resources for web designers](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/), though you might find a good jQuery solution as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but i don't change color of background radibutton, i want change color of background circle!

Comment: Ah, so you don't really mean "body background".

Comment: Thanks, Is there no other way?